# BGP "no synchronization" command not showing up in running-config

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands, cisco-ios-15

I noticed in the running config I don't see the `no synchronization` command under the BGP section. Is this a default command so I won't see it unless I change it?

Hardware / software

- Cisco 1921
- c1900-universalk9-mz.SPA.151-4.M5

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In most modern versions of IOS (since 12.2(8)T - thanks @ytti) BGP synchronization is disabled by default (and shown in the running config as such, ie `no synchronization` shows up in `show run` when you turn on BGP). As to which IOS version they decided to make it a "hidden default", I'm not entirely too sure, but you should be able to do:

```
show running-config all
```

or

```
show running-config full
```

To get the router to show the entirety of the running config, including the defaults which are normally hidden. Look for `no synchronization` in there.

Comment: It's been disabled since 12.2(8)T so many years now, ref: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094431.shtml

Comment: Yeah, I figured it had been a long time, I just didn't remember which release they decided to make "no synchronization" the default, which would make sense. As to what version they decided to make the default "hidden" in, I'm not sure.